# Cannot read csv into R Markdown: Error in file(file, "rt")

Tags: r, csv, r-markdown

I have been reading other questions on this topic (see [read.table() and read.csv both Error in Rmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834007/read-table-and-read-csv-both-error-in-rmd)), but I believe I have set my working directory fine and the answers are not adequately answering my question...

Here is my code:

````
---
title: "WQ"
author: "A"
date: "October 13, 2017"
output:
  html_document: 
    fig_height: 6
    fig_width: 12
classoption: landscape
---


```{r}
setwd("C:/Users/K/Box/Projects/DRIP/3. Data/working/R_markdown")
x <- read.csv("Nash_longform_subset.csv",as.is=T)
y <- read.csv("Nash_longform.csv", as.is=T)

```{r}
````

All files and the R markdown file are in the **same folder** (set above in the code). The code itself runs perfectly, but will not export through R Markdown...

And I get the error:

```
x Line 14 Error in file(file, "rt"): cannot open the connection calls: 
<Anonymous>... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> read.csv -> read.table -> file
```

Comment: I wouldn't use setwd within a markdown document

Comment: I would use compile the markdown once using `getwd()` to display the working directory, then use relative paths to read in your csv files, which should be nested within your package.

Comment: I still don't really know what the error is, but I just pulled in one dataset at a time in different R markdown documents, and that seems to work. Pulling in 2 into the same Rmd yields the error  above.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are missing an slash in your wd so R doesn't find the document, that's what  Error in file(file, “rt”) means. More explicitly is that R is looking for the first file in this path:

```
"C:/Users/K/Box/Projects/DRIP/3. Data/working/R_markdownNash_longform_subset.csv"
```

change your wd to:

```
setwd("C:/Users/K/Box/Projects/DRIP/3. Data/working/R_markdown/")
```

Comment: @kslayerr do you get the same error or a different one? btw tag me if you comment so i can answer faster

Comment: I get the same error as above. I found a solution (to my specific problem, I believe). I only bring in one dataset at a time and run it that way, with no error. I don't really understand why or how that works, though.

Comment: @kslayerr glad you found a solution